# Take column value to another row and make it a new column

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data set that contains an id variable and a partner id variable and a value. In other words, each observation is paired with another observation. I want to create a new variable that takes the value of one's partner and adds it as a new column.

Below I have an example data:

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(id = c(1:10),
                 partner_id = c(6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5),
                 value = runif(10))

df

   id partner_id     value
1   1          6 0.2875775
2   2          7 0.7883051
3   3          8 0.4089769
4   4          9 0.8830174
5   5         10 0.9404673
6   6          1 0.0455565
7   7          2 0.5281055
8   8          3 0.8924190
9   9          4 0.5514350
10 10          5 0.4566147
```

As I stated above, I want to add a variable with the partner's (`partner_id`) `value`. As an example, observations with `id == 1` has `partner_id == 6`, hence, I want a new fourth column (`partner_value`) where `id == 1` has `partner_value == 0.0455565`.

So the end result should look like this:

```
   id partner_id     value partner_value
1   1          6 0.2875775     0.0455565
2   2          7 0.7883051     0.5281055
3   3          8 0.4089769     0.8924190
4   4          9 0.8830174     0.5514350
5   5         10 0.9404673     0.4566147
6   6          1 0.0455565     0.2875775
7   7          2 0.5281055     0.7883051
8   8          3 0.8924190     0.4089769
9   9          4 0.5514350     0.8830174
10 10          5 0.4566147     0.9404673
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  left_join(df, 
            by = c("id" = "partner_id")) %>% 
  select(id, partner_id, value = value.x, partner_value = value.y)
```

This returns

```r
   id partner_id     value partner_value
1   1          6 0.2875775     0.0455565
2   2          7 0.7883051     0.5281055
3   3          8 0.4089769     0.8924190
4   4          9 0.8830174     0.5514350
5   5         10 0.9404673     0.4566147
6   6          1 0.0455565     0.2875775
7   7          2 0.5281055     0.7883051
8   8          3 0.8924190     0.4089769
9   9          4 0.5514350     0.8830174
10 10          5 0.4566147     0.9404673
```

Comment: Thanks, seem to work. Didn't think of doing it in that way :)

Answer (score 3):

By `match`,

```
df %>%
  mutate(partner_value = value[match(partner_id, id)])

   id partner_id     value partner_value
1   1          6 0.2875775     0.0455565
2   2          7 0.7883051     0.5281055
3   3          8 0.4089769     0.8924190
4   4          9 0.8830174     0.5514350
5   5         10 0.9404673     0.4566147
6   6          1 0.0455565     0.2875775
7   7          2 0.5281055     0.7883051
8   8          3 0.8924190     0.4089769
9   9          4 0.5514350     0.8830174
10 10          5 0.4566147     0.9404673
```

Comment: the same but in *base*: `df$partner_value <- df$value[match(df$partner_id, df$id)]`

Comment: This will fail If you have `1 6, 6 1, 2 6, 6 2`

Answer (score 2):

In base R:

```
df <- merge(df, df[-1], by.x = "id", by.y = "partner_id")
names(df) <- c("id", "partner_id", "value", "partner_value")
```